# Identity server 4 change password user info

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I am implementing change password functionality within the identity server 4 web application project. When the logged-in user click "Change Password" button from the client application it will redirect to the Identity server controller. As the user already logged in how do I get the userInfo (example AccountId) within the Identity server application without it being passed from the client, those details are stored in the clients access token.